# How access to $loop variable in nested foreach blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```
@foreach($last_articles->chunk(3) as $row)
        @foreach($row as $last_article)
                @if($loop->index!=0) {{"in $loop"}} @endif
        @endforeach
        @if($loop->index!=0) {{"out $loop"}} @endif
@endforeach
```

how to access the $loop of any of foreach, that was used in the code?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use `$loop->parent` to access the parent loop of the current loop.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (Laravel 6.8) `$loop->parent` looks like this

```
[
{"iteration":1,"index":0,"remaining":1,"count":2,"first":true,"last":false,"odd":true,"even":false,"depth":1,"parent":null},
{"iteration":2,"index":1,"remaining":0,"count":2,"first":false,"last":true,"odd":false,"even":true,"depth":1,"parent":null}
]
```

to access the parent index `$loop->parent->index`